# fancybox 2.0.6 ie7 no working

Tags: jquery, class, html, fancybox-2

i am using fancybox inline content and all other browsers work well but not in IE7.

tried to call div class rather than div id,
from: `<a class="various" href="#inline">Inline</a>`
to: `<a class="various" href=".inline">Inline</a>`

then in ie7, the pop-up works, but no content loads and with error message. "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

does inline content method only works in div id? not class?

Comment: ffffwwwhhhhaaaaat!? can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and the reason was IE7 internally modified my href="#inline" by  adding something before #inline so in rendered HTML it was different and fancybox didn't work.

I ended up with call of hack JS function to correct that:

```
function RefreshAnchorForIE7(anchorCSS) {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0") {
        var val = $(anchorCSS).attr("href");
        var index = val.lastIndexOf("#");

        if (index > 0) {
            $(anchorCSS).attr("href", val.substring(index));
        }
    }
}
```